# I have a problem drawing slanted, would grid paper help?

Tags: drawing, sketching

Or make the problem worse cause I would be relying on the grid to make my drawings straight?

I'm not talking about the grid method, just free-drawing on a dot grid or something. Even when I draw reference/center lines they end up slightly slanted and so does the rest of the picture.

Comment: Hi BL, welcome to Arts & Crafts! Slanted how? Can you give an example of what you're trying to draw? Are they perspective lines, or just anything that deviates from straight angles?

Comment: Hi! Hmm, just basic sketches of faces now. I think it has a lot to do with my positioning and the way I hold the paper. I end up viewing the drawing from a skewed POV so everything is slanted. I try to remind myself and shift the paper back every now and then, but it's hard haha. This even affects my perspective lines, so when I try and draw around the guidelines everything is slanted too. Dunno if that makes sense.

Comment: So you mean the overall structure of your drawing gets slanted, as in distorted?

Comment: Yea, cause when I'm viewing it from the side it looks fine, but when I adjust the angle it looks slightly off.

Comment: Can you upload an example of one of your works? I think that would make it a lot easier to help you out.

Comment: "I think it has a lot to do with my positioning and the way I hold the paper. "    Sounds like you answered your own question.